# SMART error Offline uncorrectable sectors is this serious?

Tags: hard-drive, smart, freenas

I install freenas and activated smartd and I got a report of 3 faulty drives.

On drive /dev/ad20 (Western digital green 1500gb)

```
Device: /dev/ad20, 4 Offline uncorrectable sectors
Device: /dev/ad20, 6 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

On drive /dev/ad12 (Western digital green 1500gb)

```
Device: /dev/ad12, 5 Offline uncorrectable sectors
Device: /dev/ad12, 5 Currently unreadable (pending) sectors
```

On drive /dev/ad14 (Brand new SSD OCZ 30gb)

```
Device: /dev/ad14, Failed SMART usage Attribute: 9 Power_On_Hours.
Device: /dev/ad14, 161 Offline uncorrectable sectors
```

I tested /dev/ad12 with DLG Diagnostic and I got no error.

Answer (score 4):

What is really important is any changes.  If those values increase then you have problems.  If they remain stable then, while not ideal, the situation is probably acceptable - assuming of course you have working backups.

Comment: Shall I just take your word for it, or is there an explanation for this reasoning?

Comment: @Phil - In short if the values are stable then the disk isn't degrading further.